# Multiple buttons to call same function in python Gtk

Tags: python, function, button, gtk

I am developing a small application using Gtk-Python, in which i have some 10 to 20 buttons, and when any of them are clicked, i want the value of the button to be appended in the text box I have done it so far by

```
button1.connect("clicked",button_function)
button2.connect("clicked",button_function)
...
```

for all the functions. Is this the only way of doing it? Or is there an elegant way? And the value of the button is specified by

```
button1._value=#something
...
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: in this way, pass the button objects in a list, call it like this, `for button in buttonslist: button.connect("clicked",button_function)`

Comment: but won't that call the functions for all the buttons at once?

Comment: You are just binding the function to click event,you can call whenever you want on any button any time.

Comment: @Srini Could you post your comment as a response so that Aswin Murugesh can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way, put button objects in a list, call it like this,

```
for button in buttonslist: 
    button.connect("clicked",button_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys,os
import pygtk, gtk, gobject

class GTK_Main:
  def __init__(self):


    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.set_title("Test")
    window.set_default_size(500, 400)
    window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit, "WM destroy")

    hbox_eq = gtk.HBox()

    buttonlist = []

    for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
      b =  gtk.Button( str(i) )
      b.set_name("YOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!")

      buttonlist.append(b)
      hbox_eq.pack_start(b, True, True, 0)

    for button in buttonlist:
      print button
      #print button.get_label()
      #print button.get_name()

    window.add(hbox_eq)
    window.show_all()

  def exit(self, widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()


GTK_Main()
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```

output:

```
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d8370 (GtkButton at 0x24348e0)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d83c0 (GtkButton at 0x24349a0)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d8410 (GtkButton at 0x2434a60)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d8460 (GtkButton at 0x2434b20)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d84b0 (GtkButton at 0x2434be0)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d8500 (GtkButton at 0x2434ca0)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d8550 (GtkButton at 0x2434d60)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d85a0 (GtkButton at 0x2434e20)>
<gtk.Button object at 0x25d85f0 (GtkButton at 0x2434ee0)>
```